# trading exit strategy

Tags: equities, trading

I have the following exit strategy under consideration.

Suppose I have n shares of stocks that I want to sell. When the price reaches n/(n-1) of the original price, I sell 1 share. When the price reaches n/(n-2) of the original price, I sell another share ...

Basically when the stock price increases, I keep on selling the shares one by one to keep the dollar amount of the stock constant.

This seems to balance the profit and risk, especially when I am not sure how much gain I can have in the stock. But I don't have a quantitative assessment of this strategy.

Has this strategy been studied already so that I can know when this strategy is a good one and when it is not a good one? If so, could anybody show me the analysis of the pros and cons of this strategy?

Answer (score 7):

There can be no rational trading entry or exit strategy based on your pnl, i.e. a function of past and current prices.  The only way to make a "strategy" is to predict, one way or another, *future* prices.  Without predictions, the most rational action is to have zero exposure.  An exception is when a trader extracts a utility from the thrill of gambling.  Another situation when exiting a position based on recent pnl is rational is to avoid a margin call on a levered position.

Comment: What does pnl mean?

Comment: profit and loss

Comment: How do you prove this mathematically? Is it the Martingale Stopping Theorem of Doob?

Comment: This question is more about common sense than math.  A rigorous approach to defining a 'rational' allocation $P_i(t)$ (positions or exposures to available strategies or securities) would require introducing a utility functional $U[\{P_i(t)\}]$.  This step involves human preferences even though it looks like math.  My preferences would include larger future profits and lower risk, which is a version of mean-variance utility.  YMMV.

Comment: "n a trader extracts a utility from the thrill of gambling" - decades ago, one could lose a little money in Las Vegas and get comped the hotel room, food, and a couple of shows - much better than just a thrill. Alas, those days are long gone.